# How to solve bad alloc() runtime error?

Tags: c++, algorithm, bad-alloc, coin-change

I am getting the std::bad alloc() exception in a code I have written. According to other answers on SO, I should free the dynamically allocated memory but the exception remains. Any leads on how I can solve it?

I am attaching the function where the error comes.

> int count(int *S, int m, int n ) {
>    int i, j, x, y;
>
> ```
> // We need n+1 rows as the table is consturcted in bottom up manner using 
> // the base case 0 value case (n = 0)
> int **table=new int*[n+1];
> for(int q=0;q< n+1;q++)
>   table[q] = new int[m];
>
> // Fill the enteries for 0 value case (n = 0)
> for (i=0; i<m; i++)
>     table[0][i] = 1;
>
> // Fill rest of the table enteries in bottom up manner  
> for (i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
> {
>     for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
>     {
>         // Count of solutions including S[j]
>         x = (i-S[j] >= 0)? table[i - S[j]][j]: 0;
>
>         // Count of solutions excluding S[j]
>         y = (j >= 1)? table[i][j-1]: 0;
>
>         // total count
>         table[i][j] = x + y;
>     }
> }
> int answer = table[n][m-1];
> delete[] table;
> return answer; }
> ```

I am basically trying to solve the coin exchange problem. n can be as big as 10^9.

Comment: Your code also leaks memory. Use vectors to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Oh yes.
But there seems to no other way. If I do not take the DP solution, I will exceed the time limit. 
For the DP solution I need this much space. Any other way to solve the coin change problem?

Comment: Also you have to delete the rows: **for(int q=0; q<n+1; q++) delete[] table[q];**

Comment: I am compiling on 64-bit, but the code eventually gets submitted to an online compiler.

Comment: Thank you user1754322. Changing that statement didn't take care of the runtime error however.

Comment: Btw, I guess S contains the value of each coin, m is the number of coins and n might be the quantity. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Notice when you allocate `table` you do it in *two* steps. You allocate `table` and then each element of `table`. To release all the memory you must also use *two* steps, each `table` element and finally `table` itself.

Change your cleanup to something like:

```
for(int q=0;q< n+1;q++) {
  delete[] table[q];
}
delete[] table;
```

...or just use `std::vector` and avoid manual memory management.

Comment: It doesn't solve the runtime error I am getting when n = 1000000000, m = 5.

Comment: @TheBlueNotebook: It sounds like you need to find a different algorithm. I can delete this answer if your actual problem isn't a memory leak.

Comment: Okay. My code works for smaller inputs. It's only when larger inputs are given that the code fails.